# How to handle all incoming requests using only one interceptor in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

i have been doing spring boot from couple of days, now i want to have security interceptor to all the incoming requests. While studying the tutorials i found that to have a class with `@Component` annotation which implements `HandlerInterceptor`

```
@Component
public class ProductServiceInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

      return true;
   }
   @Override
   public void postHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, 
      ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {}

   @Override
   public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
      Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception {}
}
```

and  then have to register this Interceptor with `InterceptorRegistry` by using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like

```
@Component
public class ProductServiceInterceptorAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   ProductServiceInterceptor productServiceInterceptor;

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(productServiceInterceptor);
   }
}
```

but am confused in this tutorial interceptor is used for only one service i.e for `Products` and my question is how to have a `single interceptor class which will intercept all the incoming requests irrespective of any controller path`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure your application you may want to look into the [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) project.

To achieve what you are trying to do you will need to use a [Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and a [FilterRegistrationBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html).

The filter will intercept every request and response from the path that you define in your registration bean.

From the [Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) javadoc:

> The doFilter method of the Filter is called by the container each time a request/response pair is passed through the chain due to a client request for a resource at the end of the chain. The FilterChain passed in to this method allows the Filter to pass on the request and response to the next entity in the chain.
>   A typical implementation of this method would follow the following pattern:
>
> 1. Examine the request
> 2. Optionally wrap the request object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for input filtering
> 3. Optionally wrap the response object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for output filtering
> 4. a) Either invoke the next entity in the chain using the FilterChain object (chain.doFilter()),
> 5. b) or not pass on the request/response pair to the next entity in the filter chain to block the request processing
> 6. Directly set headers on the response after invocation of the next entity in the filter chain.

Below a sample that filters all the requests from the root ("/*") path.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilterConfig.class);

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> registrationBean(Filter sampleFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

    bean.setFilter(sampleFilter);
    bean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

    return bean;
  }

  @Bean
  public Filter sampleFilter() {
    return (request, response, filterChain) -> {
      HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      log.info(
          "Request URI : {}",
          servletRequest.getRequestURI());

      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      log.info(
          "After filtering the request : {}",
          servletRequest.getRequestURI());

    };
  }

}
```